# d3.js loop number as variable for

Tags: d3.js

As in the example at http://bl.ocks.org/cgdnorth/7144137, I am looking to translate each boxplot that is created into the month it corresponds to. I know I can move each of the boxplots in the `.attr("transform...` when they are created:

```
svg.selectAll(".box")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter().append("svg")
                    .attr("class", "box")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.bottom + margin.top)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")") // Need to translate each boxplot by e from data[e] in the csv.foreach
                    .call(chart);
```

I would like to know how I can access the `data` key value `e` defined in `csv.forEach(function(x) {` that cycles through the data so I can multiply by the width of the box like:

```
svg.selectAll(".box")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter().append("svg")
                    .attr("class", "box")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.bottom + margin.top)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width + margin.left + margin.right)*e + "," + margin.top + ")") // Need to translate each boxplot by e from data[e] in the csv.foreach
                    .call(chart);
```

This would also be the array key that is used to draw each of the box plots.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `e` is just the index of the data array, so you should be able to use the index d3 provides to you in your `selection.attr` function:

```
.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + (width + margin.left + margin.right)*i + "," + margin.top + ")";
});
```

Note I changed your `e` to `i`.

Comment: Updated example with your help: [Average Temperature Box Plot](http://bl.ocks.org/cgdnorth/7146037). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a function as your 2nd attr() function argument. This function will be passed the nth data element for each data element in joined data.

```
.attr("transform",function(d,i){
    var xtransform = findMyXCoordinate(d,i);
    // for this value, you probably want to use 
    // margin.left + x(d)
    // where x is the d3.time.scale() function
    return "translate(" + xtransform+ "," + margin.top + ")") 
})
```

Also See [This article](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563) which shows how to easily handle coordinate spaces with margins.